# Isn't Applicative strong enough for MonadComprehensions? Why not?

Tags: haskell

It strikes me that every monad comprehension ends in a `return`. Does that not effectively make them isomorphic to applicative programming? Why do we have monad comprehensions with a `Monad` constraint instead of applicative comprehensions with an `Applicative` constraint?

This [do-like notation for Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/applicative-quoters/0.1.0.7/doc/html/Control-Applicative-QQ-ADo.html) similarly strikes me as very similar to monad comprehensions.

Comment: I may be wrong (no compiler at hand), but I think `[y|x<-[1], y<-[x]]` is a counterexample which can't be desugared using `<$>` and `<*>`.

Comment: Interesting historical note: MonadComprehensions was proposed as the notation for Monads before the do notation was invented. (Which also predates Applicative)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. You can write bind with monad comprehensions:

```
m >>= f == [ b | a <- m, b <- f a ]
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Would it be possible/sensible to translate comprehensions and perhaps do notation to applicative when no "bound" names are used on the RHS? I guess similar to arrow notation without `ArrowApply`?

Comment: @Dag "when no 'bound' names are used on the RHS?" - this is an interesting observation, and yes, it is possible: The linked quasiquoter in your question does almost exactly this. Whether it is *sensible* is another question entirely... unfortunately `Applicative` is not defined a superclass of `Monad` (though in theory it should be) so things could get ugly.